Why is the $1,\infty$ matrix norm at least the sum of column maximums?
I read this in a proof in a paper, but I don't understand why it's true. Specifically I'm referring to the very bottom of page 23 (last inequality), with a description that continues on the top of page 24 in this paper: https://openreview.net/pdf?id=wTGjn7JvYK.
Why is $|| M ||_{1,\infty} = \sum_{j=1}^n ||M_{:,j}||_{\infty}$?
They claim that they use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to prove it. I can't find anything online about the $1,\infty$ norm. But if I write out the definition, I have
$$||M||_{1,\infty} = sup\{||Mx||_{\infty}\}, ||x||_1=1$$.
if we constrained x to be a standard basis vector, this would become exactly what we want. I suppose if we want x to be a standard basis vector, this is simply a further restriction, and thus
$$sup\{||Mx||_{\infty}|||x||_1=1\}  \geq sup\{||Mx||_{\infty} | x \in \{e_j\}\} $$ .
But I didn't use the cauchy-schwarz inequality here. And also, I don't see why this argument couldn't work for any norm $||M||_{p,\infty}$.
Is there something I'm missing that the authors intended?
-Paul
